# Relative URL for 301 redirect in htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I used to have a documentation file at `https://example.com/myapp/doc/file.html`, but I have now decided to host the documentation at `https://example.com/myapp/doc/`. Note that the path can be different, e.g. `http://customer.com:8080/foo/bar/myapp/doc/file.html`.

How can I use htaccess to redirect to the correct directory? My tries were:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file\.html$ "" [R=301]
```

This puts a filesystem path in the URL and is totally unsuitable. If I wanted an internal redirect it would probably work, but I explicitly want a 301.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file\.html$ "%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/myapp/doc/" [R=301]
```

This works, but only when my app is installed into the URL root. When a customer puts it into `/foo/bar`, it fails.

How can I 301-redirect to the current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code should work from any where to redirect `file.html` in current directory to current directory itself without any hardcoding of paths. It compares `REQUEST_URI` variable (which is complete path) with the URI matched by `RewriteRule` (which is relative to current path) and gets differential in `%{ENV:BASE}` variable.

```
RewriteEngine On

# find rewrite base dynamically
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

RewriteRule ^file\.html$ %{ENV:BASE} [L,R=301,NC]
```

For example, it will perform following redirects:

- `/foo/bar/myapp/doc/file.html` to `/foo/bar/myapp/doc/`
- `/myapp/doc/file.html` to `/myapp/doc/`
- `/some/path/file.html` to `/some/path/`